# Unable to make a Build for HTC Vive project on Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, htc-vive

I'm unable to make a build for my Vive project and Unity just freezes once I put it up for Build. I'm unable to make out what's wrong. These are the last logs that I can see but I don't find much help here as well.
        [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor/Src/GI/Enlighten/Jobs/CreateEnlightenGeometryJob.cpp line 775] 
    (Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindow.cs Line: 485)

```
[00:00:00] Enlighten: Finished 140 Create Geometry jobs (1.26s execute, 0.02s integrate, 0.33s wallclock)
[PathTracer] building lightmap data asset.
[00:00:03] Enlighten: Finished 1 Layout Systems job (3.24s execute, 0.00s integrate, 3.24s wallclock)
[00:00:04] Enlighten: Finished 30 Create System jobs (3.56s execute, 0.00s integrate, 1.04s wallclock)
[00:00:04] Enlighten: Finished 1 Create SystemAtlas job (0.00s execute, 0.00s integrate, 0.01s wallclock)
[00:00:06] Enlighten: Finished 30 Clustering jobs (2.98s execute, 0.00s integrate, 1.61s wallclock)
```

Answer (score 1):

So when you hit the play button unity basically stops working. Do you have a Vive? Is it plugged in? Are you using the Steam VR example? Some more information would help.

Comment: It plays fine. When I put it up for Build, to make an exe file for Windows, that is when Unity freezes and the Build also doesn't get made. Yes, I'm working on a Vive and although making a  build has nothing to do whether the device is plugged in or not, but I've tried either ways. Yes, I'm using SteamVR1.2.2. Let me know what more information would you require. I'll post them.